# Discrete test statistics cannot form a uniform P-value?

Tags: distributions, p-value, uniform-distribution, continuous-data, discrete-data

I received this feedback on my permutation test design from a collaborator and I'm wondering if his claim is valid. My test statistics are discrete (like counting the number of red marbles found after drawing 100 marbles from a jar), and I validated that my permutation test does not show bias by demonstrating a uniform P-value distribution for 1,000 statistical tests on randomized data. Please let me know your thoughts:

"The null distribution of P-values is only expected to be uniform for statistical tests based on continuously-valued data. For statistical tests based on discretely-valued data, the null distribution is expected to be spiky and not necessarily uniform."

Comment: There are a finite number of possible values this particular p-value can take, right? Does that sound like $U(0,1)?$

Comment: I see, so albeit the the distribution may be jagged (i.e. 100 possible P-values on a histogram with 100 bins), if smoothed it should resemble more or less a uniform distribution?

Comment: I recommend visualizing the CDF instead of a histogram.

Comment: You can make the p-values truly uniformly distributed by employing a randomized test.

Comment: While its not continuous standard uniform like you get under Ho for a continuous test statistic and a point null, a conservative test forms a cdf that just touches the y=x line at each jump (sitting to the right of the uniform line). I've seen a few different names used for this property. e.g. see the terms in Definition 1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.06040.pdf though I've also seen some people call it "uniform", albeit using a quite different definition to this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your collaborator is technically correct. With a finite number of values, your CDF will have jump discontinuities in it, yet the CDF of a uniform distribution is continuous.

However, a CDF with jump discontinuities can look pretty continuous, so while your collaborator might be technically correct, the difference might not be of practical importance.

[image: Uniform CDF?]

The CDF above looks quite continuous and even looks uniform (at least to me). However, there are a finite number of points used to produce that plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 10000
x <- runif(N, 0, 1)
cdf <- ecdf(x)(x)
d <- data.frame(
  X = x,
  CDF = cdf
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = CDF)) +
  geom_point(size = 1/100)
```

(Yes, the `runif` command means that the data are simulated from a uniform distribution. However, the data explicitly plotted there do not exhibit a uniform CDF.)

If that is uniform enough to suffice for your purposes is up to you, and the answer might be that it is not, though I would be among those surprised if it is not.

A histogram for these data do exhibit some "spikes" that your collaborator mentioned.

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = X)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image: Histogram]